# Start a process as a specific user, from a WCF managed service running as LocalSystem

Tags: c#, wcf, process

Is it possible to spawn a process on a remote server, from a WCF service hosted as  Windows Managed Service, when the service is running as LocalSystem?

I need people to be able to execute things on remote servers under the context of their own accounts (basically like PSExec - which isn't an option).

I've made some half-hearted attempts to do this before, but when using process.start, cannot get the process to run as a specific user, if the Windows service hosting the WCF component is running as LocalSystem.

I know this can be acheived by other methods, but I specifically would like to know if the above is achievable - Windows service running as LocalSystem & hosting WCF service, then spawning a process as a specified user.

Thanks

Mick

Comment: Any specifics on what is going on when you try to use Process.Start?

Comment: If I specify a username and password in process.start, then the process is spawned, but dies striaght away.  I think the error message says it is an invalid application.  I don't have any working code at the moment so I can't give the exact error.  I'm trying to determine if it is possible before devoting any great amouns of time to it, so sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed04yy3t.aspx) method which allows you to specify the user under which the process will run.

Comment: Hi Darin.  I've tried that.  When the service is running as Localsystem, the spawned process kicks off, but then dies immediately with an error (I can't remember what it is off the top of my head).  I seem to remember that if I set the service to run as a Domain account, then specifying the user and password in process.start works correctly.  However, that will require getting the necessary privileges applied to a domain account on a lot of servers, which will be very difficult to push past our security guys.

Comment: @Mick, you don't need to use a domain account. Simply leave this parameter blank and it will use a local machine account.

Comment: Thanks Darin, unfortunately that will still require a local account being created and permissioned with the relevant privileges, hence wanting to run the Windows service as LocalSystem, as it already has the necessary User Rights.

Comment: Mick, did you manage to do it? We are experiencing the same problem... It would be very useful if you could share your knowledge.